# Vue.js globalEventBus catch events from window object?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, event-handling, listener, event-bus

I have a globalEventBus in vue.js that I can inject into other components to catch and react on custom events... however, I have the problem that some events come from vue.js components, and some events come from the global window object...

`globalEventBus.js:`

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import { mapActions } from 'vuex';

export const eventBus = new Vue({
    methods: {
        ...mapActions(['handlePivotItemClick', 'handleEventButtonClick',
            'handleInputRadioChange'])
    }
});

// catch custom events from vue.js components that you have emitted yourself inside vue.js components:
eventBus.$on('nms-event-pivot-item-clicked', event => {
    console.log("Event bus ###:", event.detail);
    this.handlePivotItemClick(event);
});

eventBus.$on('nms-event-button-clicked', event => {
    console.log("Event bus ###:", event.detail);
    this.handleEventButtonClick(event);
});

eventBus.$on('nms-event-input-radio-changed', event => {
    console.log("Event bus ###:", event.detail);
});

// catch global window events, but how to register and catch them on eventBus?
window.addEventListener('nms-event-input-radio-changed', event => {
    console.log("Event Window###:", event.detail);
    this.handleInputRadioChange(event);
});

window.eventBus = eventBus;
```

How can I catch both events with globalEventBus from components and global window objects? Until now, I can only catch window events with `window.addEventListener(...)` but not with `eventBus.$on('eventName',...)` what is the best approach to do it or is it possible to do it anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct. If an event is triggered on `window` you need to listen for it then.

One thing that you can do is to listen for events on `window` and then `$emit` them on your global EventBus.

This way you only have to listen to your event bus for event handling.

This approach will also let you add other sources for events, besides window.